# qml check/uncheck all checkboxes in listview

Tags: qt, qml

I have the following code to `check/uncheck all` other checkboxes in a listview. I am using the `ButtonGroup` component to achieve the same. It seems to achieve what it is intended to do but when I `uncheck all` of them and scroll through the listview, a few of the items on the top and bottom of the list are automatically checked again. What could be wrong?

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15


Rectangle {
    id: win
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    visible: true


    ButtonGroup {
           id: childGroup
           exclusive: false
           checkState: mainCheckBox.checkState
       }

       CheckBox {
           id: mainCheckBox
           checked: true
           text: "All"
           indicator.width: 15
           indicator.height: 15
           checkState: childGroup.checkState
       }

       ListView {
           id: multiSelectCheckList
           model: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40]
           height: parent.height
           width: parent.width
           anchors {
               top: mainCheckBox.bottom
               margins: 10
           }

           delegate: CheckBox {
               id: modelCheckBoxes
               checked: true
               text: modelData
               indicator.width: 15
               indicator.height: 15
               ButtonGroup.group: childGroup
           }
       }
}
```

Comment: The basic problem is that you are storing state (the check state) in a delegate of your model. Don't do that. State needs to be in the model instead, as the delegates get deleted and re-created (or even re-used if you enable that on the ListView) as you scroll the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the items in a ListView are dynamically created, that is, there is a cache. So in this case it is better to use a template to save the relevant information and then modify the template rather than the delegate.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15


Rectangle {
    id: win
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    visible: true

    ListModel{
        id: listModel
        dynamicRoles: true
        Component.onCompleted: {
            var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40]
            for(var i in numbers){
                var number = numbers[i]
                listModel.append({"number": number, "checked": true})
            }
        }
    }
    CheckBox {
        id: mainCheckBox
        checked: true
        text: "All"
        indicator.width: 15
        indicator.height: 15
        onCheckStateChanged: {
            for(var i =0; i < listModel.count; ++i){
                listModel.setProperty(i, "checked", checked)
            }
        }
    }
    ListView {
        id: multiSelectCheckList
        model: listModel
        height: parent.height
        width: parent.width
        anchors {
            top: mainCheckBox.bottom
            margins: 10
        }

        delegate: CheckBox {
            id: modelCheckBoxes
            checked: model.checked
            text: model.number
            indicator.width: 15
            indicator.height: 15
        }
    }
}
```